# how to get corresponded value of a List<string> from api in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is my API response

```
var = ''' [
{
    "entity_id": "86",
    "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "location": "Al  Ttay",
    "image_field": "1595916594oad.jpeg"
},
{
    "entity_id": "87",
    "building_name": "Azmair",
    "location": " Eyal Nasser ",
    "image_field": "1596541099s.jpeg"
},
  {
    "entity_id": "88",
    "building_name": "Bella Casa",
    "location": "Hatta",
    "image_field": "15965463423abe68a5bc11733effefeb91194_767x0.jpg"
  }
]''';
```

I am making it as a string using

```
var decoded = response as List;
var buildgnames = decoded.map<String>((e) => e['building_name']).toList();
```

how to get "entity_id" with the when select building name in a list?

like when I choose "Burj Khalifa" in a drop-down I want to get the "id" of it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` for accessing each element of list like

```
decoded.forEach((element) { 
  var entity_id = element['entity_id'];
})
```

In your case when you select the drop down button you will get the index of item use that index and fetch it like this

```
var entity_id = decoded.elementAt(index)['entity_id'];
```

Comment: This would be a bad solution, which is not really scalable. He should simply change to googles suggested way of deserialization: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: He already did the decoding work now he have `List<dynamic>` I am just telling him how he can access the entity_id in that list object

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great guide on how json and serialization works in Flutter:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Basically you create a model for your data structure:

```
class Entity {
   int entityId;
   String buildingName;
   String location;
   String imageField;

   Entity({this.entityId, this.buildingName, this.location, this.imageField});

   Entity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : 
     entityId = json["entity_id"],
     buildingName = json["building_name"],
     location = json["location"],
     imageField = json["imageField"];
}
```

When you have done that, you can deserialize your json like this using the dart:convert package:

```
var jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
var entity = Entity.fromJson(jsonMap);
```

After this you can put your entity as the data to select in the dropdown. And when you select "Burj Khalifa". You can simply check entity.id

Answer (score 0):

```
 DropdownButtonFormField(
      hint: Text("Building"),
      onChanged: ((val) {
        setState((){
        print(val. entity_id);
        selectedBuilding = val;
        });
      }),
      value: selectedBuilding ?? null,
      items: buildingList.map<DropdownMenuItem>((BuildingModel value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value.building_name),
        );
      }).toList(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.access_time)
      ),
    );
```

> You can get your selected building model :
>
> ```
> onChanged: ((val) {
>             setState((){
>           print(val. entity_id);
>           selectedBuilding = val;
>           });
>           }),
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create model class.

```
 class Building {
  String id;
  String buildingName;
  String location;
  String imageField;

  Building({this.id, this.buildingName, this.location, this.imageField});

  Building.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['entity_id'];
    buildingName = json['building_name'];
    location = json['location'];
    imageField = json['image_field'];
  }
}
```

After that convert response to Building object.

```
 Iterable mJson = json.decode(response.body);
 List<Building> buildingList = mJson.map((model) => Building.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

Show building list name and return building id when click.

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
            itemCount: buildings?.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {  
              return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _handleRowTap(buildings[index].id),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(
                          "${buildings[index].buildingName}",
                        ),
                  ));
            }));
```

And the latest.

```
_handleRowTap(String buildingId) {
//Handle click event here
  }
```